# Recursive greatest common denominator explanation

Tags: javascript, math

I found this solution:

```
function gcd_rec(a, b) {
    if (b) {
        return gcd_rec(b, a % b);
    } else {
        return Math.abs(a);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how it works and I'm stuck on the second line `if (b) {`

Apparently it's supposed to run through the function (itself) if `b` exists? is true? But this time it runs it where `a` is now the value of `b` and `b` is now the remainder of `a` divided by `b`.

Does this mean it will never return `Math.abs(a)` as long as the user puts a value for `b`???

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: `if (b)` will not succeed in this code when `b` is `0`. That is, the code exits when `b` is zero, with the result being found in `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Wikipedia explains it very well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm

> To compute gcd(48,18), divide 48 by 18 to get a quotient of 2 and a remainder of 12. Then divide 18 by 12 to get a quotient of 1 and a remainder of 6. Then divide 12 by 6 to get a remainder of 0, which means that 6 is the gcd. Note that we ignored the quotient in each step except to notice when the remainder reached 0, signalling that we had arrived at the answer.

So, in your algorithm, b is always the remainder of the previous division, and a the previous b.

If b, the new remainder, is greater than 0, it will return true in the `if` statement, so we ignore `a` and run the new algorithm, with the new inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the recursive function is called, it passes in a new value for `b` (`a % b`).  So when b reaches 0, it calls `return Math.abs(a)`.

Comment: You couldn't have explained it better than this. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find the gcd. The last abs just ensures that the result is non-negative.